# Add a specific space on top and bottom of a fbox

Tags: spacing, graphics, framed, fbox

I have a figure which rounded by fbox, I am wondering how can I add a space only at the top and bottom of the image since `\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}`add space around the whole figure.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need this (for the case that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two methods for adding a top and bottom padding inside a `\fbox`:

- If the figure is an image included by `\includegraphics` then option `trim` can be used to add the padding.
- A general method puts the contents of `\fbox` in a box and increases its height and depth.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{%
  % Negative trim values add space.
  % The amount is scaled with the image (scaled here by option "width").
  \includegraphics[width=60pt, trim=0 -40pt 0 -40pt]{example-image.pdf}%
}

\fbox{%
  % box register 0 is a local scratch register
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[width=60pt]{example-image.pdf}}%
  % The height and depth of the box are increased.
  \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0 + 10pt\relax
  \dp0=\dimexpr\dp0 + 10pt\relax
  \usebox{0}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Frame separation cannot be set in each side. Round the image also with a `\parbox`, then you can add any vertical (or horizontal) space around the image.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{5cm}{\bigskip%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\bigskip}}
\end{document}
```

A bit overkill for a simple frame, but alternatively, you can use `longfbox`:

[image: mwe2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longfbox}
\fboxset{rounded,border-color=red,padding-top=6pt,padding-bottom=6pt}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lfbox{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

Or `tcolorbox`, or `mdframed` ...